# Invalid Column name when executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures

[image]    **`

Here is my script - when I execute this stored procedure, I get an error

> invalid column name

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EdilzSaf_Landing.test_hassan123 
    @x varchar(128),
    @y varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql= N'SELECT S.name as SchemaName,
                       T.name as TableName,
                       I.name as IndexName,
                       DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
                FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS DDIPS
                INNER JOIN sys.tables T on T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
                INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
                INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
                                         AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
                WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
                  AND I.name IS NOT NULL
                  AND S.Name = ' + QuoteName(@x) + '
                  AND T.Name = ' + QuoteName(@y) + '
                  AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
                ORDER BY DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
END

EXECUTE EdilzSaf_Landing.test_hassan123 @x='EdilzSAF_Landing', @y='BUNDLE'
```

Comment: Pretty sure `S.Name = '+QuoteName(@x)+'` isn't doing what you think it does; None of the `sys` objects have columns called `EdilzSAF_Landing` or `BUNDLE`. Are you *sure* you need dynamic SQL here? Surely `@x` and `@y` should be parameters for a static query, no?

Comment: Agreed, this shouldn't be dynamic

Comment: Deserves downvoting simply due to the use of meaningless parameter names.

Comment: @SMor agreed. People need to stop that lol

Answer (score 0):

Quotename is adding square brackets to your names and breaking your WHERE clause (as the name isnt stored in the system tables with square brackets).

As others have said in the comments, this doesnt need dynamic sql.

```
declare @x varchar(128)='nsa', @y varchar(128)='Tasklist';

    set nocount on;
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);
    set @sql= N'
SELECT S.name as SchemaName,
T.name as TableName,
I.name as IndexName,
DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS DDIPS
INNER JOIN sys.tables T on T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
and I.name is not null
and S.Name = '''+@x+'''
and T.Name = '''+@y+'''
--AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
ORDER BY DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
    '
     EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
     select QuoteName(@x)
      select QuoteName(@y)
      select @sql
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the error here, which I can't copy because it's an image. None of the `sys` objects you have referenced in your query have columns called `EdilzSAF_Landing` or `BUNDLE`. Why is it looking for these columns? Well that's because of these clauses:

```sql
'...
and S.Name = '+QuoteName(@x)+'
and T.Name = '+QuoteName(@y)+'
...'
```

This would resolve to:

```sql
...
and S.Name = [EdilzSAF_Landing]
and T.Name = [BUNDLE]
...
```

There's no need for a dynamic statement here, just use a parametrised dynamic statement:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE EdilzSaf_Landing.test_hassan123 @SchemaName sysname,
                                                 @TableName sysname
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT S.name AS SchemaName,
           T.name AS TableName,
           I.name AS IndexName,
           DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) DDIPS
         INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas S ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
         INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
                                 AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
    WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
      AND I.name IS NOT NULL
      AND S.name = @SchemaName
      AND T.name = @TableName
      AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
    ORDER BY DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC;
END;
GO

EXECUTE EdilzSaf_Landing.test_hassan123 @SchemaName = N'EdilzSAF_Landing',
                                        @TableName = N'BUNDLE';
```

I've also fixed the data types for the parameters of your SP.